# Powershell Invoke-Restmethod Authorization header issue

Tags: powershell, zendesk-api, invoke-restmethod

I am trying to query the endpoint for target failures in zendesk:
https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/ticketing/targets/target_failures/

Specifically:
List Target Failures
GET /api/v2/target_failures
Returns the 25 most recent target failures, per target.

I am passing a username and password into:

```
$username
$password
```

Here is how I am constructing the request:

```
$params = @{
    Uri = "https://subdomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/target_failures";
    Method = 'Get';
    Headers = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password))); Accept = "application/json";
    } #end headers hash table
} #end $params hash table
Invoke-RestMethod @params
```

I am getting this error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":"Couldn't authenticate you"}
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod @params
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Edit: Finally got this working via the following method:

```
Connect-AzAccount
Set-AzContext "SUBSCRIPTION"
$user = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'KEYVAULT' -Name 'SECRET' -asplaintext
$pass = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'KEYVAULT' -Name 'SECRET' -asplaintext
$pair = "${user}:${pass}"
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair)
$base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
$basicAuthValue = "Basic $base64"
$headers = @{ Authorization = $basicAuthValue ; Accept = "application/json"}
Invoke-WebRequest -uri "https://SUBDOMAIN.zendesk.com/api/v2/target_failures" -Headers $headers
```

Not 100% sure why this worked and my original script did not, but if someone could explain it to me that would be super helpful.

Comment: The way you're constructing the authorization looks ok... btw you can `Invoke-RestMethod @params` here, there is no need for `-Uri $params.Uri -Method $params.Method...` See splatting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.4

Comment: can you add a link to the api documentation ? I don't see something wrong with your code

Comment: https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/

Comment: Which endpoint from that documentation ? Should also be added to your question not to a comment

Comment: Your provided code has no closing `}` bracket after the authorization header. It should be after password, before accept: `$password))) } ; Accept`

Comment: If you use the -Credentials parameter on this cmdlet and feed credentials through this parameter it'll convert the credentials to Basic auth by default.

Comment: Do you have the same account on both the local and remote machines?  For authentication to work the local and remote machines has to be in the same domain and the user needs to have a domain account on both machines.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I updated my question with the api endpoint

Comment: @jeremywat I fixed the code, I realized I forgot a line

Comment: @JacobKing Have you explicitly [enabled password-authentication for API access](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408831452954) in your zendesk profile?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I have

Comment: Sounds like a case for Zendesk support then - you've clearly followed the guidance, and if you insist the credentials are correct then there's little more anyone here can do to help you :)

Comment: So I opened a case with Zendesk support and they showed me how they are doing this using postman and curl. I was able to test and verify that approach works just fine using the username and password I have. I really need this to work in powershell though.

Comment: Updated my post with the script that worked